Is there some higher-dimensional polytope that represents the Rubik's Cube group?
I recently found a Pocket Cube and while trying to find instructions on how to solve it, I got sucked into the whole Rubik maths rabbit hole. I was wondering if the Rubik's group can be represented by some higher-dimensional Platonic/Archimedian/Catalan kind of polytope... I found this graph for the restricted pocket cube and it makes so many things obvious:

God's number is 4.
There is no superflip.
What is the fastest way from any configuration to any other?

There must be some (much more complicated) equivalent for the 3x3x3! The only resource I found were some articles on LinkedIn by Devarapally. Is a geometric representation of the Rubik's Cube graph either solved and not helpful due to the law of conservation of difficulty or is it as unapproachable as most other things Rubik?
Here are my thoughts and search results so far:

No vertex can be distinguished from any other based on the vertices and edges surrounding it [Devarapally], which tells me that we are looking for a Platonic or an Archimedian kind of polytope, not a Catalan one.
The State Space Graph Contains 4-d hypercubes as elements [Devarapally], representing twists of opposite layers.
Every node is connected to three 4-d hypercubes. No two of these hypercubes have more than one node in common [Devarapally]. These represent the three different pairs of opposite layers. Probably no Platonic polytope then. I don't know if in higher dimensions there are more possible categories in addition to Platonic/Archimedian/Catalan...
The State Space Graph Contains "cubes" of 4-d hypercubes [Devarapally]: The hyper-space diagonals of the hypercubes connect to higher-order cubes.
Quarter-Turn Metric is probably nicer than Half-Turn Metric, the latter just adds further diagonals into the hypercubes.
The shortest non-trivial cycle that returns to the solved state I could find is 12 steps long, which probably says something about the shapes between the hypercubes.
If there is some higher-dimensional polytope with 43 252 003 274 489 856 000 vertices, that is probably a strong cancidate...
God's number is 20, so the whole thing is super dense.
The largest order of an element in the group is 1260. I have no idea what can be concluded for the structure of the graph from that.
It feels like the superflip should be on the opposite side of the polytope from the solved state. I can't make sense of the fact that in QTM there are multiple configurations that are further away from the solved state than the super flip... Maybe the graph is planar or a torus or hyperbolic or some weirder thing that arises in higher dimensions... On the other hand, a tetrahedron also has no single furthest vertex from another vertex.
Wikipedia mentions some subgroups, I am assuming this is the equivalent of cubes being contained in a dodecahedron like this which probably doesn't help much.
The graph might also be some higher-dimensional equivalent of this thing, which would probably not be very helpful for path planning.
I also found this question but I don't really understand what they are talking about.

EDIT:
Higher-dimensional Platonic solids are either n-simplices (n+1 vertices), n-cubes (2^n vertices) or n-cross-polytopes (2n vertices). Hence, if it's a Platonic solid, it must be a 43 252 003 274 489 855 999 dimensional simplex (but there God's number would be 1), a 21 626 001 637 244 928 000 dimensional cross polytope (but there God's number would be 2) or a 65.2294 dimensional cube (but there God's number would be 65.2294). So Platonic solids are out as well. The structure that Devarapally describes (with three hypercubes meeting in each vertex) also smells most like Archimedes out of the three. However, there is probably some hardcore stellation going on. Or some other thing that can only happen in higher dimensions.
Any further pointers appreciated.

You may like my webpage about Cayley Graphs of puzzles which explores some of these ideas.

Sorry I didn't get back for so long. I read the article, it's pretty good! The most relevant point is probably "Often it is easier to just try out all the possibilities than it is to build the graph." :P
There are probably so many possibilities for higher-dimensional Archimedian solids that this doesn't really lead anywhere. But maybe might still be interesting to discover more local structures.
